# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model .. that has not been installed and created AbstractUser models not able to login

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

**`AUTH_USER_MODEL` error solved in EDIT3. Passwords still will not save on user creation via form.**

I'm using Django 1.5 playing around with the new user override/extension features, and I am not able to register new users via my registration form - only via the Admin. When registering via the registration form, I get the following error:

`Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'poker.PokerUser'`

models.py:

```
class PokerUser(AbstractUser):
    poker_relate = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    token = models.EmailField()
    USER_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Staker'),
        ('2', 'Horse')
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    username1 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=40)
    username2 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=40)
    username3 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=40)
    username4 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=40)
    username5 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=40)
```

`PokerUserForm` model:

```
class PokerUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PokerUser
        fields = ('username','password1','password2','email','user_type','token','username1','username2','username3','username4','username5',)
```

I've attempted to change the model in the `PokerUserForm` model to use `get_user_model()` instead of explicitly defining the model by setting `model = get_user_model()` instead of `model = PokerUser` but then I receive the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'poker.PokerUser' that has not been installed
```

My `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is setup in my `settings.py` like so:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'poker.PokerUser'`

On we go - my Registration view in `views.py`:

```
def UserRegistration(request):
    player = PokerUser()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PokerUserForm(request.POST, instance=player)
        if form.is_valid():
            player.email_address = form.cleaned_data['email']
            player.user_type = form.cleaned_data['user_type']
            # if player is staker, token is their own email. otherwise their token is their staker's email and
            # their relation is their staker
            if player.user_type == '1' or player.user_type == 'staker':
                player.token = player.email_address
            else:
                player.token = form.cleaned_data['token']
                staker = PokerUser.objects.get(email=player.token)
                player.poker_relate = staker
            player.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PokerUserForm()
    initialData = {'form': form}
    csrfContext = RequestContext(request, initialData)
    return render_to_response('registration/register.html', csrfContext)
```

**EDIT1:**

[According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms), the `UserCreationForm` must be recreated for use with custom user classes.

I overrode the entire `UserCreationForm` as follows:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
        }
    username = forms.RegexField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30,
        regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text=_("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                    "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages={
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = PokerUser
        fields = ('username','password1','password2','email','user_type','token','username1','username2','username3','username4','username5',)

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            PokerUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except PokerUser.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'])
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

And this was able to resolve this error:

`The Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'poker.PokerUser'`

Now, the users get created but are not able to log in. When I check the users in the admin, all of the information seems to be correct except for the password. Adding a password manually in the admin does not seem to work correctly. Still, adding users via the admin work correctly.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm still unable to login as any of my AbstractUser models created via the registration form. I have completely overridden the `UserCreationForm` as outlined above, and am unable to implement 
`get_user_model()` with this error:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'poker.PokerUser' that has not been installed`

The Django code for `get_user_model()` is:

```
 def get_user_model():
    "Return the User model that is active in this project"
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db.models import get_model

    try:
        app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.')
    except ValueError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
    if user_model is None:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    return user_model
```

Since I have `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'poker.PokerUser'` setup in my `settings.py`, this should work. I've verified this through the Django console:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
Out[14]: 'poker.PokerUser'
>>> from django.db.models import get_model
>>> app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.')
>>> user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
>>> user_model
Out[18]: poker.models.PokerUser
```

However the implementation still does not work correctly.

If you've read this far, thanks!

**EDIT3:**

`AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'poker.PokerUser' that has not been installed` has been fixed. I accidentally had the `UserCreationForm` that I recreated in `poker.models` instead of `registration.forms`, so when I ran `get_user_model()` that was assigned to `poker.PokerUser`, it couldn't resolve since it was already in that location.

Now the only issue left is that when creating new users, their passwords will not save. I've narrowed it down to a single method in the `UserCreationForm` by placing print statements here:

```
def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    print password1
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    print password2
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'])
    print password2
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    print self.cleaned_data["password1"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

The `print password1` and `print password1` statements in `clean_password2` display the plain text password, but `print self.cleaned_data["password1"]` in the `save` method is blank. Why is my form data not being passed to the save method?

**TL;DR** `AbstractUser` model creation is working in both Admin and via registration form, but only the users created via Admin are able to login. The users created via the registration form are unable to log in and seem to be saved without a password - all other information is saved correctly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok there were three issues here for me, so I'm going to address all of them since I am pretty sure the first two will come up for someone else.

- `Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'poker.PokerUser'`

This was due to using but not recreating the `UserCreationForm`. When using custom models in 1.5, some model forms are available out of the box but this one must be recreated. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) for the docs.

- `The Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'poker.PokerUser'`

While I had `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'poker.PokerUser'` set in my `settings.py`, I was calling `get_user_model()` from the `poker.models` location. You must call `get_user_model()` from a different location. Moving my form to `registration.forms` and calling `get_user_model()` from there worked correctly.

- New users not saving

This was just a brain fart on my end. In my `UserRegistration` model I was manipulating various fields from the form. When I passed those fields back to `UserCreationForm` for the `save()` method, I was not passing the password fields with it. Woops!

Answer (score 31):

I've run into this a few times.  It's always been an import issue.  Suppose we have core/models.py that implements a custom user and imports a symbol from another file (say Else):

```
from Something import Else

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    pass
```

And then we have another file that uses CustomUser and also defines Else.  Let's call this something/models.py:

```
from core.models import CustomUser

class Else(models.Model):
    pass

class AnotherClass(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
```

When core/models.py goes to import Else, it evaluates something/models.py and runs into the AnotherClass definition.  AnotherClass uses CustomUser, but CustomUser hasn't been installed yet because we're in the process of creating it.  So, it throws this error.

I've solved this problem by keeping my core/models.py standalone.  It doesn't import much from my other apps.

Comment: Am I annoyed because I am a novice in Python, or is the Python folk also generally irritated by nasty import issues? It's impossible to keep track of them as the project grows!

Comment: @nakajuice This issue is pretty much a Django special. The user model situation is a total garbage fire and its been one since I started using django a decade ago and it baffles me its allowed to go on like this. When it wont let you install the user model, because the user model is not installed, the framework needs to be smart enough to say 'Hang on, this feels like a paradox, lets try it some other way"

Comment: For me, the problem is that I imported the model in the `admin.py` before doing making & running the migration. I commented out the code from the `admin.py` and run the migrations and then it all worked fine.

Comment: @RobJones, can you provide further details on "by keeping my core/models.py standalone. It doesn't import much from my other apps.".

Answer (score 15):

It can happen if you forget to register your app in settings. In your settings.py file add the name of your app in the list of INSTALLED_APPS. I hope this helps.

For instance, if your app name is 'users' it would look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ......

  'users'
]
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case updating, proper app_label in meta solved this issue

```
class APPUser(AbstractUser):
   password = models.TextField(blank=True)

   class Meta:
     app_label = 'app_auth'
     db_table = "app_user"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you created multiple directory to maintain structure in your project, Check directory of the User model that you have written.
Just import the User model in **init**.py of that directory.

Example:

```
app directory: 
     app/
       views/
         __init__.py
         views.py
       models/
         __init__.py  ->  from .user_model import User
         user_model.py -> class User(AbstractUser):
```

In my case i got the solution in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I override the built-in User model and made the class abstract that caused this issue. Therefore, changing abstract=False in metaclass resolved the issue.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionMixin):
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

      class Meta:
      abstract = False
```