# ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL in upgrading django and django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm trying to upgrade an old Django 1.4 installation to Django 1.8, and with that also django-registration 1.0.0 to django-registration-2.0.4

I'm running into an issue with `RegistrationForm`, which says it's impopertly configured. `MyRegistrationForm` is simply:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

and when I load the home page, I get:

```
...
File "/mypath/wwwmyproject/src/website/myproject/core/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myproject.core.views import MyRegistrationForm
  File "/mypath/wwwmyproject/src/website/myproject/core/views.py", line 31, in <module>
    from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
  File "/mypath/wwwmyproject/src/website/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/forms.py", line 24, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/mypath/wwwmyproject/src/website/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 155, in get_user_model
    "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed
```

I've seen many Stackoverflow questions with the same subject, in particular:
[AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model that has not been installed ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699598/auth-user-model-refers-to-model-that-has-not-been-installed-and-created-abstr) but still I can't pinpoint my issue.

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.auth` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings? Please post your `settings.py`.

Comment: Yes, `django.contrib.auth` is at the top of `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: You seem to have `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings pointing to `auth.User` - is this a custom model or you want  `django.contrib.auth.models.User`?

Comment: No, it's not a custom model. I think that comes from the function call `User = get_user_model()` in `django-registration`'s `forms.py`

Comment: Do you mind posting your `settings.py` file? I am interested to know if there's any `AUTH_USER_MODEL` definition in it.